# Normalization of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, normalization

I have a 2D matrix of dimension 365x28 (i.e., 365 rows and 28 columns). I am trying to normalize this using the following code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    double[][] X = new double [365][28];
    double[][] X_min = new double [1][28];
    double[][] X_max = new double [1][28];

    double[][] X_norm = null;

    X_norm = normalize(X, X_min, X_max);// error in this line

public static double[][] normalize(double[][] ip_matrix, double[][] min_bound, double[][] max_bound)
{

    double[][] mat1 = ip_matrix;

    double[][] norm = new double[mat1.length][mat1[0].length];

    for (int i = 0; i < mat1.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= mat1[i].length; j++)
        {
                norm[i][j] = (mat1[i][j] - min_bound[i][j] / (max_bound[i][j] - min_bound[i][j]));// error in this line
        }
    }

    return norm;

}           
}
```

But when i run this i get an index error. I understand that there is something wrong with min_bound[i][j] and max_bound[i][j]. But i do not know how to rectify this. Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```
Error: exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the full error that you are getting.

Comment: yup..i will edit it now.

Comment: this code gives me an 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 28`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well your issue is pretty obvious if you think about it. Remember arrays start indexing at 0.
So in the method normalize in the first for loop with the var int "i", it goes up to 365 because your check the length of the 2D array X where min_bound and max_bound only have the size of 1 and 28. Think

this works assuming that min_bound and max_bound is always [1][(some value)]

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat1.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= mat1[i].length - 1; j++) {
                norm[i][j] = (mat1[i][j] - min_bound[0][j]
                        / (max_bound[0][j] - min_bound[0][j]));// error in this
                // line
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < mat1.length; i++)
```

i goes to 365 and you call

```
norm[i][j] = (mat1[i][j] - min_bound[i][j] / (max_bound[i][j] - min_bound[i][j]));
```

where min_bound is 1x28

Hence, you get indexoutofbounds exception